# C# possible null pointer exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
public string execute(User user, dynamic data)
{
    if (user == null || data == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    user.log("Getting user {0}", user.id);
}
```

`user.id` is `uint` type

`user` on the last line is marked with a warning:

> Possible System.NullRefferenceException

How could `user` be null? Is it Visual Studio bug or am I missing anything?

Comment: Is `user.id` a nullable type? Or `user.log`?

Comment: This is easy to fix. First solve the halting problem, then apply that to this code heuristic.

Comment: @DavidSetty no, its uint

Comment: It doesn't give me that warning in VS2015. You should show your complete method though. There's no return value in the non-null branch.

Comment: this shouldn't even compile as you aren't returning a value from your method.  I'd fix that first.

Comment: I have never seen this message _"Possible..."_ emitted by the VS compiler, it seems instead a misleading diagnostic from ReSharper